# About undefined properties inside objects array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So, im starting with javascript again, and i got stuck in this declaration issue.

Declaration 1:
[declaration with separated objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG9Z6.png)

```
var fruta = {
    nome: "Cereja",
    cor: "Vermelha",
    ehBoa: true
};
var fruta2 = {
    nome: "Kiwi",
    cor: "Verde",
    ehBoa: true
};
var fruta3 = {
    nome: "Figo",
    cor: "Verde",
    ehBoa: false
};

var frutas = [
    {fruta}, 
    {fruta2}, 
    {fruta3}
];

console.log(frutas[2].cor);
```

This one returns Undefined
Declaration 2:
[declaration with objects declared inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0vMG.png)

```
var frutas2 = [
    {nome: "Tomate", cor: "Vermelho"}, 
    {nome: "Siciliano", cor: "Amarelo"}, 
    {nome: "Melância", cor: "Verde"}
];

console.log(frutas2[2].cor);
```

This one returns "Verde" as it should.
My question is, why one of them is undefined, while the other one isnt? Is this related with Hoisting?

Comment: Add your code to the text.

Comment: The syntax of `{val}` is shorthand for `{val: val}`, where the first `val` is the key name (it is literally `val`), and the second `val` is the value stored in the variable `val`. So your array contains objects with keys `frutas` etc. with the values being the objects stored at `frutas` etc.

Comment: Thank you !! That really helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That because in 1st one you are passing it by wrapping inside object again.

For 1st time you need make following change to get it work.

```
var frutas = [
 fruta,
 fruta2,
 fruta3
]
```

Comment: Thank you!! I didnt notice that, but it makes total sense, also it works!